# Stop activity on alertdialog

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, dialog

Is there anyway to create an alertdialog in activity and stop activity execution until the alertdialog close? Something like .net inputbox. My problem is that I can display the alertdialog but the code execution continues while dialog is displayed.

Comment: show the code. it would help us to understand better